# Angular2+ Bundling of all the component css/scss into one single file

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

As of today in my Angular 6 project the page  it includes a lot of component stylings and other styling as well.

How to Reduce  styling to only one css file.

And please do let me know the Pros and Cons of doing or not doing it

[image]